# Cohomological interpretation of gluing conditions

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cech-cohomology

This question comes from a problem of theoretical physics. Stated in its simplest form, there is a complex line bundle over $S^1$. For each $z \in S^1$, the fiber $F_z$ is the complex eigenspace of a unimodular real 2x2 matrix $M$ (it is understood that $|tr(M)|<2$), the other eigenspace is the fiber over $1/z$. As such, the line bundle is trivial, but there is a further structure: there is a $\mathbb{Z}/2$ action $F_z \to F_{1/z}$ such that $U \in F_z \to \sigma U \in F_{1/z}$ where $\sigma=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$.

What I am looking for is an equivariant section $z\to U(z)$, that is, satisfying the gluing condition $U(z)=\sigma U(1/z)$. Using a cover of $S^1$ with 2 open sets $o_1$ and $o_2$ overlapping at $z=1$ and $z=-1$, it is easy to see that it suffices to consider the gluing condition at these two points only.
Now, while this can always be done at one of the two points $z=\pm 1$, it cannot always be done at the other point $1/z$. It may happen that the gluing condition be $U^1(1)=-\sigma U^2(1)$.

So I have a $\mathbb{Z}/2$ action on $S^1$ represented by $z \to 1/z$ and a $\mathbb{Z}/2$ action on $F$ represented by $\sigma$, but I could also choose $-\sigma$. So somehow, I have 2 group actions on the fibers and I would like to interpret the fact that both have to be used as a non-triviality of the bundle, i.e., the fact to add a "$-1$" as an obstruction to having a continuous equivariant section.

I would like to have a description of this situation in terms of a cohomological space. From the gluing conditions, this looks like Cech cohomology with "twisted" coefficients, but I do not know how to put his in clear mathematical form.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at equivariant cohomology? I don't fully understand your construction, but I think this might be close to what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the insight! Yes that should probably be it, however I do not feel fluent enough in algebraic topology to use this tool...